# Android skip Activity and put it last

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a skip button and it have to do what i draw.
i honestly don't know how can i make this happen.
The code actually have to skip the current activity and put it as last.
if the activity's question was answered, there is no skip.[here i draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbzll.png)
I have tried a few things but it's beyond my powers.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, c1_2.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: 26 activity is a lot dude, you need variable to hold name or number of activity that skipped, create parent activity and hold/store value there

Comment: Do it then dude ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use arrayList or Queue for keep your activityes, then use it to start Activity.

try this.

```
    final ArrayList<Class> activities = new ArrayList<>();
    // add your activity---------------
    activities.add(c1_1.class);
    activities.add(c1_2.class);
    activities.add(c1_3.class);


    //----------------------------

    butonSkip=findViewById(R.id.skip);
    butonSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Class firstActivity = activities.get(0);
            startActivity(new Intent(c1_1.this,activities.get(0)));
            activities.remove(0);
            activities.add(firstActivity);

        }
    });

    //-----------can change activities data
    // activities.set(1, c1_3.class);
```

Comment: it works a little but i don't know how to properly edit it to all the activities.

Comment: you can change activities data with this : activities.set(1, c1_3.class);

Comment: ok i will do more editing on this code.. it works anyway in what i want. Thanks mate:)